# ActionbarSherlock: Hide actionbar while displaying tabs

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

My UI uses ABS with tabs (`ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS`) and a bunch of fragment layouts being loaded for each tab.

There is one tab where I need to *hide the ActionBar* (to reclaim some screen space) for the UI but calling `getSupportActionBar().hide();` would nuke the tabs along with the ActionBar.

I was wondering if there is was anyway at all where I could hide the actionbar without affecting the tabs?

EDIT: Actually, come to think of it, the Actionbar doesn't do anything except showing the app branding/icon. So I wouldn't mind hiding the ActionBar altogether and just showing the tabs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is called a 'collapsed action bar'. It will be automatically hidden if you don't display the title and the home icon:

```
 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

If you want to have both tabs and actions, you can use a split action bar and have the actions (menus) at the bottom.

Comment: Yes. Google it if you don't trust me :)

Comment: Had to try it to believe it... works like a charm. Thanks - have an upvote :)