# Hide tabs in viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tabs

I am using `Actionbarshelock` library. I have three tabs. each tab contains a `fragment`. In my middle tab I have `sliding drawer`. I want to hide `action bar` as well as tabs from screen so that i can gain more space for sliding drawer. I hide the action bar using `hide' method but don't know how to hide the tabs and show only that middle fragment in whole screen with sliding drawer open.

I have tried

```
requestWindowFeature(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
```

It hides tabs but it has to be set before adding fragments and `setContentView`.

Comment: refear this link

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12928092/actionbarsherlock-hide-actionbar-while-displaying-tabs][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12928092/actionbarsherlock-hide-actionbar-while-displaying-tabs

Comment: Thanks! Got the solution myself. `findViewById(android.R.id.tabs).setVisibility(View.Gone);`

Comment: If you got your answer then remove the question